# The hidden order not to be ignored

Tags: encoded-message

Have a go at this riddle:

> Нidden in this іs an order, one so important that it may cost your life. Yet those that ԁo not know will not seе it, so look carefully beyond that which is seen, for your life depends on itǃǃǃ

It's a lot harder than my first one :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The hidden order is

> Ніԁеǃǃǃ

which is found by gathering all the characters in the riddle whose Unicode code points are above 128 (outside the ASCII range, in other words).